# Missing DLL file in emgucv in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, image-processing, xamarin, cross-platform, emgucv

Im Making an Image Processing Cross platform mobile application using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015.When I import the dll files which are relevant to emgucv an error shows up saying

```
DllImport attempting to load: 'opencv_core220'.
DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App1.Droid/files/.__override__/libopencv_core220': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/App1.Droid-1//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App1.Droid/files/.__override__/libopencv_core220" not found'.
```

What can I do to fix this Error.